# !SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, pdo

i am working on a pdo script and the result i see "!SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected "
    i really need help with this cos am confused; the script is:

```
 <?php

//connecting to the database
$serverhost = 'localhost';
$serverdb = 'charles';
$serveruser = 'root';
$serverpassword = '';


//using try and catch pdoexception errors

try {
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:$serverhost;serverdb=$serverdb;", $serveruser, $serverpassword);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $bad = $connect->query('select * from users');
    var_dump($bad->fetchAll());
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getmessage();
}

if ($connect) {
    echo 'database successful!';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect parameter pass in PDO connection. You need to add  `host and dbname`

Change

```
$connect= new PDO("mysql:$serverhost;serverdb=$serverdb;" , $serveruser, $serverpassword);
```

To

```
$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=$serverhost;dbname=$serverdb', $serveruser, $serverpassword);
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @charlyo Saty asked for you to accept their answer, and politely I might add.

Answer (score 1):

You need to try this instead of your $connect line 
`$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=$serverhost;dbname=$serverdb', $serveruser, $serverpassword);`

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong as your `$connect= new PDO("mysql:$serverhost;serverdb=$serverdb;" , $serveruser, $serverpassword);`

supposed to be 
`$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=yourhostname;dbname=yourdbname;" $user, $pass);`

as per manual says.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

class Conexion {

    private static $conexion;

    public static function abrir_conexion(){
        if(!isset(self::$conexion)){
            try {
            include_once 'config.inc.php';

            self::$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host'.NOMBRE_SERVIDOR.':dbname=' .NOMBRE_BD, NOMBRE_USUARIO, PASSWORD);
                self::$conexion -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            self::$conexion -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

            } catch (PDOException $ex) {
                print "ERROR:" . $ex -> getMessage() . "<br>";
                die();
            }
        }
    }  
    public static function cerrar_conexion(){
        if(isset(self::$conexion)){
            self::$conexion = null;           
        }
    }
    public static function obtener_conexion(){
    return self::$conexion; 
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your explanation

Comment: this post doesn't address the question at all